# C# & XLW 5 - how to raise an exception with sensible error message displayed in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

Using xlwDotNet, I have created a simple function which returns one number. Sometimes, something goes wrong, and I am trying to propagate an exception message to Excel.

When i use `throw new Exception("Message")`, Excel just shows `"System.Exception : "` as the message back is sent on a number of lines and the message is cut off as the cell shows only the top line.

How to propagate the error message to Excel and disable all other text, i.e. to show just "Message" and not "System.Exception xxxxx" pls?

Comment: Have you got any news on that?

Comment: Yes, see my solution at http://jiripik.me/2012/06/17/project-financialdataforexcel/ and the source code at http://www.assembla.com/spaces/FinancialDataForExcel/wiki. There you should find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
private static cellMatrixException ReportMessage(string errorMessage, string mainCategory, string minorCategory)
{
    var theContent = new ArgumentList(mainCategory);
    theContent.add(minorCategory, errorMessage);
    return new cellMatrixException(errorMessage, theContent.AllData());
}
```

See my solution at http://jiripik.me/2012/06/17/project-financialdataforexcel and the source code at  http://assembla.com/spaces/FinancialDataForExcel/wiki.